# jQuery mobile page navigation issue with IndexedDB

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation, indexeddb

Let's have a simple jQuery mobile application with two pages. something like this:

```
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
   <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
   <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Now, when I'm on Page 1 and create an IndexedDB database, the DB is assigned to my start URL "pages.html". Then, I navigate to Page 2 an can access the same IndexedDB. Everything is OK until now.

But, when I'm on Page 2 and click the browser's refresh button, the browser loads the page "pages.html#page2". Now the IndexedDB is assigned to the URL "pages.html#page2" and that is another database than of "pages.html".

How can I workaround this issue and get always the same database, even when user makes a browser refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be seeing different databases unless the two URLs have different origins. [Source:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB)

> IndexedDB adheres to a same-origin policy. An origin is the domain, application layer protocol, and port of a URL of the document where the script is being executed. Each origin has its own associated set of databases. Every database has a name that identifies it within an origin.
>
> The security boundary imposed on IndexedDB prevents applications from accessing data with a different origin. For example, while an app or a page in http://www.example.com/app/ can retrieve data from http://www.example.com/dir/, because they have the same origin, it cannot retrieve data from http://www.example.com:8080/dir/ (different port) or https://www.example.com/dir/ (different protocol), because they have different origins.

Are you really seeing different databases at http://example.com/pages.html#page1 and http://example.com/pages.html#page2? Or is the URL changing in the second case somehow, maybe to https://example.com/pages.html#page2 or http://subdomain.example.com/pages.html#page2?

Comment: I found the problem: When I open the page as file like "file:///E:/indexedDB/pages.html" then I get different databases. But everything is OK, when I open from HTTP-Server like "localhost/indexedDB/pages.html".

Comment: Yeah, depending on your browser, file:// URLs often don't work.